# Timeout expired for SQL Procedure

Tags: .net, sql-server

When more number of people is accessing same sql procedure in the . net application, it shows the timeout error.

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Some times it also shows

> Transaction (Process ID 179) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

We increased the *Connect Timeout* and *connection pool size*, but still the issue happens. The procedure is written with transaction.

How can I resolve this issue?
Any pointers to reproduce error in development environment would also be helpful

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This question isn't exactly about SQL...)

Comment: try to incerase commandTimeout also

Comment: MS SQL server 2016. When I am calling that procedure from C# code i am getting those error.

Comment: C# code is   DataSet updtDs = Helper.ExecuteDataset(cn, "GS_MGS_SaveMyGoalSheet", CommandType.StoredProcedure, null, parameterValues);

Comment: i think this is not caused by .net application, you can check whether the process in your procedure. Is it run by many user? I believe your procedure having adding/changing/removing data thus is causing deadlock. Try to [save deadlock graph(SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/save-deadlock-graphs-sql-server-profiler?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) and find out the root cause

Comment: If the query deadlocks you need to fix the query. You haven't posted anything relevant though, just the name of a stored procedure. This has *nothing* to do with timeouts and connection pools.

Comment: for more clearance you need to post your stored procedure

Comment: Deadlocks occur when connection A is trying to acquire update locks on a row or table held by *another* connection, B, that also wants to lock the rows held by A. This has nothing to do with timeouts. It means the queries are keeping too many locks for too long. You can bypass the problem in most cases by using SNAPSHOT isolation, but that won't fix the actual query issues

Answer (score 0):

Run [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422764/how-to-find-the-deadlock-reason-in-sql-server-ro14) to get the deadlock reports. That will help identify the queries and resources involved that lead to the deadlock.

Deadlocks and timeouts are often symptoms that query and/or index tuning is needed (locking more rows than  needed) or a restrictive isolation level (`SERIALIZABLE`) is being used (holding courser grained locks for longer periods). Examine the execution plans to ensure minimal rows are touched.

Make sure the stored procedure includes `SET XACT_ABORT ON`. This will ensure an explict transaction started by the proc code is rolled back immediately in the event of a timeout. Otherwise, following a timeout, the connection with the open transaction will be returned to the connection pool and not rolled back until the connection is reused and reset, or physically closed by connection pooling due to inactivity.