# Transaction deadlock in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Getting below transaction deadlock error while executing a stored procedure in SQL Server 2017.

> Transaction (Process ID 67) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

Executing the stored procedure, which internally calls many other stored procedures based on the parameter passed to master stored procedure.

Transaction isolation level set to `READ_COMMITTED`.

Database restrict access type is `MULTI USER`.

Help me to avoid or resolve this deadlock issue. Thanks.

Comment: Impossible without the actual queries. Deadlocks are caused by buggy queries. Either multiple connections try to update to the same table with conflicting locks, or a single stored procedure ends up generating multiple transactions that lock those tables or rows.

Comment: What does this procedure do?

Comment: One thing is clear though - `READ_UNCOMMITED` is *not* a solution. It means you'll read dirty data. It won't fix the bug in the queries. It *may* cover up the bug for a while, but in the end, the queries will either start generating garbage or end up deadlocking again

Comment: Sorry @Panagiotis Kanavos, it is READ_COMMITTED, my typo mistake.

Comment: @Zeina, this stored procedure calls the other stored procedures. This SP takes id as input, lookup on the mapping table with id, and get the list of stored procedures to run. and prepare the parameters for the list of the stored procedure and then execute it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yeah I agree without actual query difficult to debug. but here 100's of stored procedure this master SP is running based on the Id.

Comment: to give you a hint. If one of these called procedures opens a transaction writes in a certain table while other transaction is taking place and writing on the same table a deadlock is resulted. Try to check the running scripts in the time you are getting deadlock, or you can open the profiler with the deadlockgraph to get the command deadlocking your query.

Comment: @NaveenKumar if you agree, you also realise there's no way to help with a code bug for code we can't even see. All people can do is point to articles about techniques to avoid deadlocks, which boil down to writing good queries and being careful

Comment: You can use SNAPSHOT ISOLATION level to mitigate deadlocks and blocking up to a point. If the big stored procedure ends ups trying to update the same rows from different connections, it can deadlock itself.

Comment: Recent deadlock information is available in the `system_health` extended event trace. Run the query in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52422764/how-to-find-the-deadlock-reason-in-sql-server-ro14) and add one of those to your question.

Comment: You can *NOT* use NOLOCK or READ_UNCOMMITTED. [You can end up with more locks](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere), not just garbage data or duplicate data. You can also get unexpected runtime errors

Comment: Adding that query/index tuning often avoids deadlocks by touching the minimal amount of data needed. That's the first step I suggest as it improves performance too.

Comment: I didn't write those queries, I'm just trying to debug and resolve the deadlock issue. I could see a table with the hint ROWLOCK is getting inserted and updated. If these operations happened parallelly will this be one of the reasons for deadlock?

Comment: Sure @DanGuzman, let use that query and come back with the point.

Comment: I have gone through most of the stored procedures which are calling internally by the master procedure. Here, what I see common in all the child stored procedure is, the common table with hint ROWLOCK is getting used in all SP's for INSERT and UPDATE. Also, ROWLOCK is specified in both INSERT and UPDATE statements. Only this is the table in all SP's which is getting inserted or updated. Is there any problem with ROWLOCK?